macOS : Correctly apply a semi-transparent system custom highlight color with shell command
I successfully applied a system custom highlight color with the following shell command:
defaults write -g AppleHighlightColor -string "0.400000 0.400000 0.700000 1.000000"
But I noticed that when I apply the custom color via shell command, I get a non-transparent color. Whereas when I apply the custom color via the System Settings menu, I obtain a more suitable semi-transparent color.
I tried to change the opacity of the custom color before applying it with the shell command by decreasing the alpha value, but that doesn't change the result :
defaults write -g AppleHighlightColor -string "0.400000 0.400000 0.700000 0.500000"
Something I noticed using defaults read -g AppleHighlightColor after applying the custom color with the command and via System Settings:

after I applied the color with the shell command: 0.400000 0.400000 0.700000 1.000000

after I applied the same color via System Settings: 0.400000 0.400000 0.700000 Other



Try defaults read ... after setting using System Settings to see what it did, maybe.

Interesting! After I applied the color via the shell command: 0.400000 0.400000 0.700000 1.000000, and after I applied the same color via System Settings: 0.400000 0.400000 0.700000 Other.

I found the answer to my question. Thanks for your comment.

As when the color is applied via the menu of
System Settings, replace the alpha value of the color (X.XXXXXX) with Other.
Correct shell command:
0.400000 0.400000 0.700000 Other


So it is possible to obtain either a semi-transparent or full color. But is it possible to choose the opacity of the color?

No, given the limitations of macOS to date.
